# ASP / GetRows & Count

Tags: asp-classic

To enhance performance and resources, I've just started to use getRows() on a few of my scripts. I have just come across an issue, which I'd like to ask about.

I was doing this to get the recordset and to get the count:

```
If NOT rs.EOF Then
    arrResultSet = rs.GetRows()
    arrRowCount = UBound(arrResultSet,2)
End If
```

But then I realised I was missing a record so I added 1 to my count:

```
If NOT rs.EOF Then
        arrResultSet = rs.GetRows()
        arrRowCount = UBound(arrResultSet,2) + 1
End If
```

But now I get an error later in my script when I try accessing the data array which is purely down to adding one to my count:

```
For iCounter = 0 to arrRowCount
    ...some code...
    If LCase(Trim(peopleWord)) = LCase(Trim(arrResultSet(1,iCounter))) Then
    ...some code...
Next

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'
Subscript out of range: 'lcase(...)'
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `For` is going from the index of 0 to the index of the `arrRowCount`.

So, for example, if you have three records, you are going from 0 to 3, which is 4, right? IIRC, we used to do this: `For iCounter = 0 to arrRowCount - 1`

**Edit**: Perhaps this example will help you. This [web page](http://www.userfriendlythinking.com/Blog/BlogDetail.asp?p1=7013&p2=117&p7=3001) details why using `GetRows` yields a performance improvement, so I think you're on the right track. I have included the entire code sample, but you are interested in the part at the end. It has less code, and fewer variables, than you are using. It looks cleaner, simpler.

```
' Establish the connection object
strConn = "[connection string goes here]"
set dbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADO.Connection")
dbConn.Open strConn

' Establish the recordset object
set rsCustomers = Server.CreateObject("ADO.Recordset")
set rsCustomers.ActiveConnection = dbConn

' Load the recordset object based on supplied query
strSQL = "SELECT RecID, FirstName, LastName FROM Customers"
rsCustomers.Open strSQL

' Push the results into a two-dimensional array
dataArray = rsCustomers.GetRows()

' Cleanup the objects. We do it here instead of at the end because the data
' has already been placed into an array. This is an advantage in that we can release
' memory sooner.
rsCustomers.Close
set rsCustomers = nothing

dbConn.Close
set dbConn = nothing

' Retrieve the records performing business logic where necessary
jMax = ubound(dataArray, 2)
for j = 0 to jMax

    'Additional business logic here

next
```

Comment: This worked, thanks @DOK. Just to confirm, I keep the **UBound(arrResultSet,2) + 1** but use **For iCounter = 0 to arrRowCount - 1** when looping?

Comment: Yes, but that seems a little awkward, doesn't it? Check out my edit.

Comment: Actually, sorry to be a pain, I respect your help, but I don't understand the example. It doesn't **+1** to the **UBound** count and the **for j = 0 to jMax** does not have **-1**

Comment: Hope u don't mind me asking more, my code works but like ti fully understand the correct method :)

Comment: I can hear the gears grinding. Basically, you can stick with your +1 and -1 approach that you know works. Or you can comment out that code and try this other simpler approach and step through it until it makes sense to you. You might also try reading that article. As I see it, your basic struggle is over looping through something starting at an index of 0 and mixing that with count, which is not zero-based. Good luck!

Comment: The gears haven't got any teeth left... but you hit the nail on the head with your last comment, I now understand where I was getting confused - the starting index of the loop and the count work differently. I appreciate your answer and the few extra words, thanks.

Comment: Sheesh, glad we got that worked out. Been there, stripped my own gears many times, glad to help.